# Using 2 3way switches in a single pole double gang box

Tags: wiring

I have a two gang box that I am trying to install 2 3way smart light switches into that require a neutral connection to work properly. The 3 way switches have a neutral wire in, a hot wire in and two traveler wires coming out of them. The two gang box has all the whites wires connected together with the black wires running to the two separate light switches. How would one go about wiring these two switches so they run the lights separately?

Comment: First off, tape the travelers with yellow tape for easy identification. take pictures before disconnecting anything and provide us with them.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, unless they are already smart switches.  Are you aware that a bare or green wire is ground, not neutral?  3-way switches are complicated, **colors mean nothing**, and often the only way you can tell what's going on is by examining how it was wired before.  This conversation won't even continue without a much more detailed description or much better, photos of what's in the junction box.  You can [edit] your question to add this.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "The 3 way switches have a "neutral wire in, a hot wire in and 2 traveler wires coming out of them".  Then you said, "all the whites are connected". So that needs clarification.

There are several ways of connecting 3 way switches. my preferred way is power in to the "first" switch, 14/3 to the "second" switch, then from there to the fixtures.   No code taping required, conceptually the simplest.   I sounds like yours "might" be wired that way, but again, need clarification.   If it is wired that way, the neutral (white) from your smart switches just need to be tied in with the other whites already there.   But double check.

I know this isn't a complete answer, but I don't have enough brownie points to "comment" yet. Sorry.